# Videos in Internet Explorer with sticky header

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, video

I have no idea how to even properly word this question.  I have searched and found nothing similar to this so I am not sure exactly how to get this to operate properly.

In Firefox everything works totally fine, in Safari everything works totally fine.
In Internet Explorer it is a mess. I haven't tested Opera yet because I do not have that browser, but I will be testing it later.

On the website, best example is the [videos page](http://kerimthedj.com/new/category/videos/), the viedos displayed thus far (all youtube for now) are floating OVER the header, however the text is floating under the header in Internet Explorer.  It is not supposed to do that, in Firefox and Safari it displays correctly where the header is sticky, and all the content scrolls UNDER the header

[Image Example](http://i62.tinypic.com/24d1mxw.png)

Please help.

Comment: Can you post a small, reproducible example of the issue with your HTML and CSS?

Comment: What version(s) of IE, specifically?

Comment: @MattD any and all versions of IE, specifically right now that example given in is IE11.

Comment: I don't think you actually mean any and all versions of IE, as that would be going back to version 1. :P

Comment: @katana314, I unfortunately do not even know where to begin to give you the css and HTML.     The WP theme I'm using is Toivo-Lite.  anywhere where a video is used it overlaps like that so I'm not exactly sure WHICH codes to give.

Comment: @MattD, well correct, the one that I am using right now and can preview at work is IE11. I do not know how it shows in any other older versions, but I want it to work properly in every possible version and every possible browser.